# jQuery .each function don't work properly on html table

Tags: php, jquery, html, html-table

I have an issue with getting dimensions of a table in jQuery.

I have table which is generated from a loop like this:

```
if(something) {
    echo '<tr class="trclass" height="'.$a['percentHeight'].'%" colspan="'.$a['col_span'].'">';
}

if(something else) {
    echo '<td class="tdclass" width="'.$a['percentWidth'].'%" rowspan="'.$a['row_span'].'">';
    if (condition == 1) echo $action['1'];
    if (condition == 2) echo $action['2'];
    if (condition == 3) echo $action['3'];
}
echo '</td>';
```

Where col,row_span and width and height and action are form database.

1. On every page this table might be different.
2. Dimensions of a table's skeleton are fine and actions are displaying in appropriate cells, but I want to fit the action dimensions to the cell dimensions.

But when I try to only display in the console the hight of each cell like this:

```
$('#table tr').each (function() {

    console.log($('td').height());
```

or this:

```
$('.tdclass').each (function() {

    console.log($(this).height());
```

it's displaying only one number and I can't change the css of each cell. Can someone tell me how to do this properly?

Comment: `console.log($(this).height());` I think it displays one number because all might have the same height, check the console for repeated values.

Comment: answer from @bhansa seems correct. Another point, I don't think you can assign percentage value to height attribute, better use CSS (style="height: X%)..Or use it in TD instead of TR..COLSPAN is also for TD not TR

Comment: In the console, is there a number in a circle to the left of the message?

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#table tr').each (function() {
    console.log($($(this).find('td').get(0)).height());
});
```

OR

```
$('#table tr').each (function() {
  $(this).find('td').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).height());
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$("table").find("td").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).height());
});
```

You can check it in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dq9xjhL8/)